# Plotting 3000 data vs date in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have 3000 data which are registration numbers and every reg.number corresponds to a date. Some dates have several registration numbers. It looks like this:

Date   - - - - - -  Registration number

08.04.2015 - - - -     QW-JSD

09.04.2015 - - - -     VV-KKY

09.04.2015 - - - -     VV-TWE

11.04.2015 - - - -     GH-ERY

12.04.2015 - - - -     QW-LOP

So we need to plot this in excel date vs registration number. How can we do this? Is is it possible to plot it in excel?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please clarify your queston? What do you mean by plotting data? Creating a chart / pivot...?

Comment: @MátéJuhász if it's possible, we were thinking to use scatter

Comment: Scatter of what? scatter plot requires to numerical variables, you have only one.

Comment: @MátéJuhász yes you are right but i don't know how to do that either. We just need to show on a graph, chart or something, these registration numbered aircrafts used on corresponding dates. For example, On April 18 we had QW-JSD and VV-KKY next day we had QW-LOP etc.

Comment: Still there is nothing to visualize. You can use a pivot to show codes grouped by date.

Comment: @janty: your first step is to define what you want to accomplish.  What's the purpose for displaying the data?  What concept are you trying to visualize?  Are you interested in the specific reg numbers or just quantities of reg numbers?  Are you trying to show level of activity or historical sequence?  Or did somebody just assign you with the task to put all of the data in a chart and make it look pretty?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in several ways using Pivot Tables.

The output to aim for is likely to depend on how many aircraft and how many dates you are processing. The smaller number should end up in columns.

In your example data, to get the aircraft in columns and the dates in rows, turn the table into an Excel table then insert a Pivot Table using the data.

In the Pivot settings, Drag the date column to ROWS and the Registration column to COLUMNS and then also drag the registration column to VALUES. You can swap the COLUMNS and ROWS to get dates across the top.

Of course, this may leave you with a very sparse data view. Careful filtering of the data will let you see the wood for the trees.

This does not, of course, end up with a chart. However, once you have the data, you could choose a stacked bar chart to show the data visually. You cannot use a scatter plot as you don't have enough data for that.

[image: data table]

[image: pivot table output]

[image: pivot table settings]

[image: pivot chart stacked bar]